# In band Controller with Mininet

Tags: openflow

Please I want to test the in Band Controller with mininet, I found the code (there http://windysdn.blogspot.fr/2013/10/in-band-controller.html ) but i don't know how to integrate (or write) it in mininet. 
Can anyone help me please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Mininet (mininet.org)
2. Copy/paste the code you found (which is a script for creating a mininet topology and starting mininet with that topology) into a python script (.py)
3. Run python script, and see Mininet start-up.
4. Take the Mininet tutorial on mininet.org, and learn the hard, but good and efficient, way as everyone else

PS: You should probably do #4 first.